# VB.net MVC understanding and binding

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to seperate my code logic from my gui as in MVC principles, what I am trying to achieve is quite simple I believe

I have my Form1, which contains a textbox and button, once the button is clicked it loads a function in my controller class which adds a string to a database using entity and then should update the textbox with this name.

I thought what I would need to do is pass the original form through and then databind to the textbox object on the form, this is where I have come unstuck though, as my logic fails...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private mf As New MainForm(Me)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mf.buttonClick()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MainForm
    Private Property a As Form
    Public Sub New(ByVal s As Form)
        a = s
    End Sub



    Function buttonClick() As Boolean

        Dim context As TestDBEntities2 = New TestDBEntities2
        Dim newCategory As tTable = New tTable
        newCategory.Name = "Test1 " & Today.DayOfWeek
        context.tTables.Add(newCategory)
        context.SaveChanges()
        Dim current As String = newCategory.Name
        a.DataBindings.Add("text", "TextBox1", current)

        Return True

    End Function

End Class
```

and my error:
Cannot bind to the property or column Test1 6 on the DataSource.

Am I looking at this the right way? Or am I so far off that there is an obvious reason this doesn't work?

Any input would be appreciated! Whats the best way to pass data back to a source without returning it in as a result of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider changing your code a bit, so that it reflects more the [MVC structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx):

- use [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx) to *exchange data* and *indicate action triggers*, instead of using the form object
- normally the **controller** has knowledge of the **form** and not the other way around, so swap this in your project. This reflects also the first point

So a possible solution for a Windows Forms application could look like this:

The form that has one button and one text field, one event to signal the button click and one *WriteOnly* property to fill the TextBox from outside the form:

```
Public Class MainForm
    Public Event GenerateAndShowEvent()
    ' allow text box filling
    Public WriteOnly Property SetTextBoxContent()
        Set(ByVal value)
            generatedInputTextBox.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub generateAndShowButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles generateAndShowButton.Click
        ' forward message: inform the subscriber that something happened
        RaiseEvent GenerateAndShowEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The controller class has knowledge of the form, creates it, binds (listens) to the form's button click event and makes the form ReadOnly for the world (exposes the form):

```
Public Class MainFormController
    ' the form that the controller manages
    Private dialog As MainForm = Nothing

    Public Sub New()
        dialog = New MainForm()
        ' bind to the form button click event in order to generate the text and response
        AddHandler dialog.GenerateAndShowEvent, AddressOf Me.GenerateAndShowText
    End Sub

    ' allow the world to access readonly the form - used to start the application
    Public ReadOnly Property GetMainForm()
        Get
            Return dialog
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub GenerateAndShowText()
        ' create the text
        Dim text As String = "Test test test"
        ' access the Database ...
        ' give the generated text to the UI = MainForm dialog!
        dialog.SetTextBoxContent = text
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now what left is to create first the controller, that creates the form and use the form to show it. This can be done like this:

Create an **AppStarter** module with a `Main` method:

```
Module AppStarter
    Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        ' create the controller object
        Dim controller As MainFormController = New MainFormController()
        ' use the public property to get the dialog
        Application.Run(controller.GetMainForm)
    End Sub
End Module
```

In your project settings uncheck the *enable application framework* setting and set the `AppStarter` module as the start point of your project:

[image]

Now you have a Windows Form Project using the MVC pattern.

If you still want to use DataBinding for the TextBox control, then create a [Data Transfer Object or DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that represents the fields you will transfer from your controller to the form:

```
Public Class DataContainer
    Private t As String
    Private i As Integer

    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return t
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            t = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return i
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            i = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then add a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your TextBox and configure it to use the *DTObject*:

[image]

Now bind the TextBox control to the DataBinding control:

[image]

What left is to add a public setter for the TextBox data binding control in the form:

```
Public Property TextBoxDataSource()
    Get
        Return TextBoxBindingSource.DataSource
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value)
        TextBoxBindingSource.DataSource = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and transfer the data from the controller:

```
Private Sub GenerateAndShowText()
    ' create the text
    Dim text As String = "Test test test"
    ' access the Database ...
    ' give the generated text to the UI = MainForm dialog!
    'dialog.SetTextBoxContent = text
    Dim data As DataContainer = New DataContainer
    data.Text = text
    data.Id = 1 ' not used currently
    dialog.TextBoxDataSource = data
End Sub
```

The binding can also be set programmatically - instead of doing this over the control property window, add the following code in the constructor of the form:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    ' bind the TextBox control manually to the binding source
    ' first Text is the TextBox.Text property
    ' last Text is the DataContainer.Text property
    generatedInputTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", TextBoxBindingSource, "Text"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the Add method.

The first argument is the name of the control's property to which you are binding.  This should be "Text", not "text".

The second argument is an object that contains the data you want to bind.  You have passed the name of the target control, rather than the source of the data.  You are also binding to the form rather than the text box.  So what you have said is that you want to bind the *form's* text property to data that can be extracted from the string "TextBox1".

The third argument says where to go to find the data.  For example, if you passed a FileInfo object for the second argument, and you wanted to bind the file's path, you would pass the string "FullName", because that is the name of the property containing the data you want.  So you have told the binding to look for a property on the string class called "Test1 6", which is why you have received the error message saying it can't be found.

I think what you want is

```
a.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", newCategory, "Name");
```